# 10Mbps bidirectional wireless transmission with an MCU

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, wifi, bidirectional

I have a [Teensy 3.6](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/paulstoffregen/teensy-35-and-36) microcontroller it has the following specs

- 180 MHz ARM Cortex-M4 with Floating Point Unit
- 1M Flash, 256K RAM, 4K EEPROM
- Microcontroller Chip MK66FX1M0VMD18 (PDF link)
- USB High Speed (480 Mbit/sec) Port
- 2 CAN Bus Ports
- 32 General Purpose DMA Channels
- 22 PWM Outputs
- 4 I2C Ports
- 11 Touch Sensing Inputs
- 14 Hardware Timers

I want a way to communicate with the microcontroller with a speed of 10Mbps in a short indoor range.

I have been searching a lot but could not find any helpful information. I found the following Wifi solutions but they all do not support that high amount of data.

- ESP8266
- ESP32
- Realtek RTL8710
- EMW3265

I also thought of using [ENC28J60 Ethernet to SPI Header Board](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ENC28J60-Ethernet-to-SPI-Header-Board-/182222033581?hash=item2a6d4792ad:g:VgYAAOSwZVlXmTaU) and connect the ethernet port to a router but not sure if will be able to get 10Mbps

I just want a simple way to communicate with the MCU remotely 10Mbps is it that difficult ?

Comment: Yes, for a microcontroller it is. What do you want to do that requires 10Mbps?

Comment: @immibis I want to know if it's possible and if it is how? If not why? and what would be the max data rate that I can easily get.

Comment: according to http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/raspberry-pi-foundation/1404450/raspberry-pi-3-review-wi-fi-tests-and-benchmarks, even a *raspberry pi 3* can only achieve 11.98Mbit/s over Wi-Fi @ 10 meters. And that has a 1.2 GHz ARM Cortex-A53 quad-core processor, so...

Comment: @vicatcu I need the GPIOs and PWM pins of the MCU so what can I do to interface the Raspberry pi 3 with the MCU and get the 10Mbps transfer rate? So the raspberry pi 3 takes care of the wireless communication ?

Comment: Is it possible to do it via the microcontroller's USB port? Teensy 3.6 claims that it has 480Mbit/sec high-speed USB port

Comment: Sure you can, although you should be aware that USB 2.0 uses a lot of overhead, and 50 Mb/sec is a reasonable upper limit. But USB isn't wireless, now, is it? And USB doesn't support multiple masters, so you'd need to be careful of your protocol to get bidirectional data in the same sense you do with ethernet or  wifi.

Comment: If you can implement USB host functionality on the teensy and handle a USB wifi device (i.e. create a custom driver). however I have a feeling the cpu speed will be the limiting factor. Fyi usb is not a simple protocol.

Comment: @RyanGriggs This seems like a very difficult task. Is there anything with plenty of GPIOs, timers and PWM pins with integrated Wifi chip that can achieve 10Mbs speed?

Comment: "I want... 10Mbps... I found the following Wifi solutions but they all do not support that high amount of data... ESP32" - https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=126

Comment: How about a pc with an attached digital IO card? Or, if you don't need extremely fast io, just connect an arduino to a pc. Then you can get your 10mbps via the pc while having access to multiple digital io.  Without more details about the project and intended purpose it's hard to recommend products.

Comment: The ESP is absolutely capable of achieving that. But more to the point, what are you trying to transmit at that speed? Where does this data come from? Most microcontrollers couldn't saturate a 10Mbit link with useful data.

Comment: @RyanGriggs The digital IO card seems very interesting I didn't know about that before.  Bruce somehow I didn't read that I just read it's a little better than ESP8266 so I thought it is not up to the task. I will check it again.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ATWILC1000 from Atmel. It is a 802.11bgn "SPI network card" (or SDHC). You have to implement lwIP in your application. It should definitely work at 10Mbps if your MCU and bus is fast enough.

You could also look at TI eg. CC3100MOD (as far as I remember they have IP stack build in so I am not sure about the speed).

Answer (score 1):

According to your documentation page, your board has

- Ethernet MAC, capable of full 100 Mbit/sec speed

So you just need to wire the RMII interface and SPI control pins to a suitable Ethernet PHY.  The documentation mentions that a LAN8720A is known to work.

Answer (score -1):

If line-of-sight, use LEDs (HP and others make high-speed LEDs) and photodiodes.

Comment: What you're suggesting seems non trivial to me, so please enlighten us to which modulation scheme you suggest and what off-the-shelf parts are available.

Comment: The IRDA standard has 115,000 bits/second using ReturnToZero, at 10% bit period. Simply coming to 50% provides 575,000 BPS. Of course the next 200,000X to reach 100GigaBits is the fun part. Ohhh. this questioner only wants 10Mega, not 100Giga. Gotta run; will be back.

Comment: you're avoiding my question.

Comment: LEDs? very impractical

Comment: If you're that close, use fiber optics or just plain old ethernet!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of looking for a high bandwidth data link, consider looking for efficient compression / decompression options for whatever it is you are trying to transmit. There are very few applications I can think of that demand this kind of sustained througput.

Comment: This is a valid idea, but (lossless) compression doesn't reduce the amount of data drastically in general case. The OP will still have to send those compressed ~5Mbps somehow.